# how to rename a key value in a linux file

Tags: linux, bash, performance, shell

I need to rename a word/field in main.dev.ts in a react project

the file is  under build/app/main.dev.ts

need to change like - `ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_SNAME : abc` to `ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_SNAME :def`

code is :-

```
}
process.env.ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_API_KEY = process.env.ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_API_KEY ? process.env.ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_API_KEY : 'cfghjdkw-123e-123e-6756346474-ufhdfg223';
process.env.ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_BRAND_NAME = process.env.ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_BRAND_NAME ? process.env.ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_BRAND_NAME : 'Abc';
process.env.ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_SNAME = process.env.ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_SNAME ? process.env.ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_SNAME : 'abc';
console.log("process.env.ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_SNAME", process.env.ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_SNAME);
```

tried this but its not renaming

```
sed '/^ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_SNAME : abc /s/=.*$/= ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_SNAME : def/' main.dev.ts
```

any help appreciated...!

Comment: The `python` tag is misleading.

Comment: Changed the tag

Comment: You don't tell sed that you want to **substitute** something. Have a look [here](https://www.mybluelinux.com/sed-tutorial-how-replace-or-substitute-file-contents/).

Comment: `cd` to the project directory and run the following command: `sed -i 's|\(ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_SNAME : '\''\)abc\('\''\)|\1def\2|g' build/app/main.dev.ts` - substitute the `abc` and `def` parts as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

sed 's/process.env.ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_SNAME : 'abc'/process.env.ELECTRON_WEBPACK_APP_SNAME : 'def'/g' main.dev.ts

Comment: Tried this unfortunately it's not renaming the file.

Comment: @linuxadmin : You can't rename a file with `sed`. Files are renamed with `mv` or `rename`. Actually, I don't see from your question that you want to change the name of the file as well.

Comment: @user1934428 Actually my question is to rename 'abc to def in above code . I just tried sed only.Also its not a file ,if its a file we can use mv or rename its a key value inside a code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).